# How do I group columns into a field containing the data?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query, when I use:

```
CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(wu_paqueteproducto.extra1),' ',GROUP_CONCAT(wu_paqueteproducto.producto)) as elproducto
```

I get something like this

```
+--------+---------+----+---------------------------------------------+
| poliza |   cct   | // |            elproducto                       |
+--------+---------+----+---------------------------------------------+
|   0001 | kjjk565 | // | 1,2,2,6,1 pr001,pr002,pr003,pr004,pr005     |
+--------+---------+----+---------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to have it like this?

```
+--------+---------+----+---------------------------------------------+
| poliza |   cct   | // |            elproducto                       |
+--------+---------+----+---------------------------------------------+
|   0001 | kjjk565 | // | 1 pr001, 2 pr002, 2 pr003, 6 pr004, 1 pr005 |
+--------+---------+----+---------------------------------------------+
```

The table wu_paqueteproducto have this data:

```
| ids  | extra1   | producto |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0001 |        1 | pr001    |
| 0002 |        2 | pr002    |
| 0003 |        2 | pr003    |
| 0004 |        6 | pr004    |
| 0005 |        1 | pr005    |
+------+----------+----------+
```

This is my full query

```
SELECT 
wu_polizas.poliza,
wu_polizas.cct,
wu_polizas.paquete,  
wu_escuelas.director,
wu_escuelas.localidad,
wu_escuelas.nombre_mun,
wu_escuelas.nombre,
wu_facturashijo.empresa,
wu_bancos.banco as nombrebanco,

CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(wu_paqueteproducto.extra1),' ',GROUP_CONCAT(wu_paqueteproducto.producto)) as elproducto

FROM 
wu_polizas  
INNER JOIN wu_escuelas ON (wu_polizas.cct=wu_escuelas.cct)
INNER JOIN wu_facturashijo ON (wu_polizas.factura=wu_facturashijo.clave)
INNER JOIN wu_bancos ON (wu_polizas.banco=wu_bancos.ids)
INNER JOIN wu_paqueteproducto ON (wu_polizas.paquete=wu_paqueteproducto.paquete)


WHERE
wu_polizas.factura=002

GROUP BY
poliza

ORDER BY  
poliza
```

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no problem in MySQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) is the solution, so I would start by questioning why you think you want to do this.

Comment: well, i need to get a customer order within a field, and i need that format: "1 pencil, 2 pens, 1 notebook, 100 clips" and while i can use PHP to just create it, i wanted an sql solution to be able to work on navicat.  And actually it got resolved with group_concat and concat, i was just messing with the order. tnx! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `CONCAT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT` instead of the other way around:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(wu_paqueteproducto.extra1, ' ', wu_paqueteproducto.producto)) AS elproducto
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0426f/2) a solution than you can translate easily to your query:

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( a char(1), b char(1),  i int);

insert into t values 
( '1', 'a', 1 ),
( '2', 'b', 1 ),
('8', 'x', 2),
('9', 'y', 2);
```

**Query**:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS(' ', a, b ))
from t
group by i
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0426f/2/0)**:

```
| GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS(' ', a, b )) |
|--------------------------------------|
|                              1 a,2 b |
|                              8 x,9 y |
```

Comment: this is better than me.. you should use this

Comment: thanks, i'm new at posting, have read the rules, and hope i did not a bad job asking. but any feedback about how to ask better, is always welcome :D. i'll read it again anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
wu_polizas.poliza,
wu_polizas.cct,
wu_polizas.paquete,  
wu_escuelas.director,
wu_escuelas.localidad,
wu_escuelas.nombre_mun,
wu_escuelas.nombre,
wu_facturashijo.empresa,
wu_bancos.banco as nombrebanco,
GROUP_CONCAT(wu_paq.custom) as elproducto

FROM 
wu_polizas  
INNER JOIN wu_escuelas ON (wu_polizas.cct=wu_escuelas.cct)
INNER JOIN wu_facturashijo ON (wu_polizas.factura=wu_facturashijo.clave)
INNER JOIN wu_bancos ON (wu_polizas.banco=wu_bancos.ids)
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, CONCAT(extra1, ' ', producto) AS custom FROM wu_paqueteproducto) AS wu_paq ON (wu_polizas.paquete=wu_paq.paquete)


WHERE
wu_polizas.factura=002

GROUP BY
poliza

ORDER BY  
poliza
```